# ElasticSearch - Find matches with exact value

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I'm new working with elastic search and I'm trying to make a simple query work. I'm using elasticseach 2.3. I can't use a newer version I'm limited by another technology I'm using.

Basically I have News stored in the database with a title, a source and a publication date.
The query I'm trying to make should search for all the news that contain a certain keyword, come from some sources A or B and have a publication date in the range given.

So far I have this:

```
    {  
        "query":{  
            "bool":{  
                "must":[  
                    {  
                        "bool":{  
                            "should":[  
                                {  
                                    "match":{  
                                        "source":"SOURCE_A"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match":{
                                        "source":"SOURCE_B"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                   "match":{
                                       "title": "keyword"
                                   }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "filter":{  
                    "range":{  
                        "publication_date":{  
                            "gte":"DATE_FROM",
                            "lte":"DATE_TO"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if a given source starts exactly the same as another source (for example: "SOURCE" and "SOURCE ABC") they are both included in the result. I would like to match exactly the same source.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

The index is being created by Django Haystack but given its limitations I need to query the database myself. The index mapping is the following:

```
    {
      "myindex": {
        "mappings": {
          "modelresult": {
            "properties": {
              "django_ct": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "django_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "publication_date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "source": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ascii_analyser"
              },
              "summary": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ascii_analyser"
              },
              "text": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ascii_analyser"
              },
              "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ascii_analyser"
              },
              "url": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ascii_analyser"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index. `GET index/type/_mapping`. It seems that  `source` is of type `string`.

Comment: Yes source should be type string. I've added the index mapping in the post. Thanks!